# Always HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false in MVC4 with windows authentication mode and not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, custom-authentication

I am trying to do customAuthorization in MVC when the authentication mode is "windows"

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        #region if
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { .......}
     }
```

But always IsAuthenticated is returning false. I don't know how to invoke windows authentication before the onAuthorization(..).

But when i do like this:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        #region if
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { .......}else{
         **base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);**
         }
     }
```

The onAuthorization() method is hitting repeatedly because of the base.onAuthorization() and in the second attempt IsAuthenticated is returning true.

May i know the reason for this behavior?

When i googled results came up saying that IsAuthenticated will be true in Forms Authentication mode but not in Windows mode. As mentioned in the below link

http://www.anujvarma.com/windows-ad-authentication-and-the-authorize-attributelogin-popup/

Please Help me.

Comment: `OnAuthorization` is called when authorization is *requested*. Simply, the user is never authenticated yet at this point, because that happens later.

Comment: Hi, The issue is solve. I disabled allowanonymous property in IIS server settings and it started working as expected i.e the user is being authenticated before hitting onauthorization(..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved. I disabled allowanonymous property in IIS server settings and it started working as expected i.e the user is being authenticated before hitting onauthorization(..).

Comment: Solved my problem too. Thanks.